# Expectation of B(1) times stochastic integral?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I need to find the value of this expectation:

$$\mathbb{E}\left(B(1) \int_0^1 f(t) dB(t)\right)$$

$B=(B(t))_{0\leq t\leq1}$ is a standard Brownian motion on $[0,1]$ and $f=(f(t))_{0\leq t\leq1}$ is deterministic function on $[0,1]$. I am not sure where to start? Thank you

Comment: I forgot $f\in\mathbb{L}^2 ([0,1])$!

Comment: If you leave out pertinent information, you can edit your question to include it.  Also, when you pose a question here, it is expected that you state the source of the problem, show any work you have done on it, and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that are appropriate to your skill level.

Answer (score 2):

Hereis the point $B(1)=\int_0^1dB_t$ plugging this in your problem gives :

$$\mathbb{E}\left(B(1) \int_0^1 f(t) dB(t)\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(\int_0^1dB(t) \int_0^1 f(t) dB(t)\right)$$

Now remember Itô's isometry and get :

$$\mathbb{E}\left(B(1) \int_0^1 f(t) dB(t)\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(\int_0^1 f(t) dt)\right)=\int_0^1 f(t) dt$$

And you are done.

best regards